# Probability: marbles in bag question

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

If you have 5 marbles in a bag, 2 of them are red and 3 of them are white, what is the probability that you take out 2 red marbles out of the bag back to back? No replacement.

Comment: Are all five marbles taken from the bag?

Comment: I believe so, would that alter the answer?

Comment: It definitely would.

Comment: Can you explain?

Comment: The probability for this event will depend on the number of marbles withdrawn, as more marbles adds more opportunities

Comment: Thank you to for the clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all five marbles are removed from the bag one by one, then there are
$$\binom{5}{2}$$
orders in which the marbles could be removed since two of the five positions must be filled with red marbles.

Two red marbles can be drawn back to back in four ways since the first red marble must appear in one of the first four positions.

Thus, the probability that two red marbles are drawn back to back when all five marbles are removed from the bag one by one is
$$\frac{\binom 41}{\binom{5}{2}} = \frac{4}{10} = \frac{2}{5}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$P = \frac{2}{5} \cdot \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{10}$$

Comment: It’s a question on a math competition, the answer they determined is 2/5, can you see how they might reach that answer?

Comment: @Jaysen In that case, the question must be asking for the probability of drawing the red balls on consecutive draws when drawing all five balls without replacement.

Comment: Yes I believe so